# How to disable slide down close the bottom sheet in react native reanimated-bottom-sheet?

Tags: react-native

I want my bottom sheet stay in position, i mean when bottom sheet drag down not closing the bottom sheet.

```
function OnWheels() {        
  return (
    <Container>
      <MapView
        style={[styles.mapView]}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: -6.307263,
          longitude: 106.756841,
          latitudeDelta: 0.09,
          longitudeDelta: 0.05,
        }}
      />
      <BottomSheet
        enabledBottomClamp={true}
        initialSnap={1}
        borderRadius={20}
        snapPoints={[350, 180]}
        renderContent={renderContent}
      />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: did you try having: `enabledGestureInteraction={false}` ?

Comment: yes i already try `enabledGestureInteraction={false}` but gesture swipe up disabled too, i dont want swipe up gesture disabled.

Comment: so i guess there is no option to disable only down gesture.